# How to solve LCD problem that numbers are disappered or blurred?

Tags: c, stm32, lcd

i had some trouble with my stm32 project about custom LCD using HT1622. LCD display all number i want but some position number is blurred or disappeared. In addition, numbers have  fewer bit 1 are almost blurry, i don't know this error because of hardware or software. Hope somebody give me some advice.
(Sorry because of bad English)

Here is the code i shift bit to HT1622:

```
void HT1622_Digit_1(uint8_t _value, uint8_t _status, uint8_t _addr){

    _seg = _convert_7_segment(_value);///turn number to hex code
    _enCS();///enable CS pin
    _writeMode();   ///write mode
    temp = 0x20;

    for(i=0; i<6; i++)///find address
        {        
        _write_bit(_addr & temp);
        temp = temp >> 1;
    }

    if(_status == DIS) ///all bit 0 if dont want display
{        
        for(i=0; i<8; i++)
            _write_bit(0);
        _disCS();
        return;
    }

    temp = 0x01;///display number

    _write_bit(_seg & (temp << SEG_D));
    _write_bit(_seg & (temp << SEG_C));
    _write_bit(_seg & (temp << SEG_E));
    _write_bit(_seg & (temp << SEG_G));

    _write_bit(_seg & (temp << SEG_B));
    _write_bit(_seg & (temp << SEG_F));
    _write_bit(_seg & (temp << SEG_A));


    if(_addr == DIGIT4_ADDR)/// display the symbol
        _write_bit(S_Flag_1 & S20);
    else if(_addr == DIGIT5_ADDR)
        _write_bit(S_Flag_1 & S5);
    else if(_addr == DIGIT6_ADDR)
        _write_bit(S_Flag_1 & S9);

    _disCS();   ///end 

}
```

LCD like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxhu8.jpg)

I hope can get some advice my problem

Comment: It is an contrast issue. Hardware problem

Comment: Or you keep clearing and writing.